# Is there any secure way to store credentials in React Native for Windows?

Tags: windows, react-native, jwt

I'm a web developer. I'm learning to develop a Windows app (and maybe going to mobile later). My first approach is to use React Native because it's pretty familiar with web development, and it's made for multiple platform. But, when searching for an authentication method such as JWT, I don't see any way to store it securely in React Native for Windows.

I search the docs ([here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/security)) for it but the Windows section is missing. I wonder if there is any secure way to store credentials in React Native for Windows rather than AsyncStore?